# Submit button is not firing the modal

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

The submit button should fire the 'check' function and also fire the bootstrap modal. But the later is not happening. It works when I change the html to type="button". Isn't it possible to  fire the bootstrap modal with a submit button?

```
<form [formGroup]="guessForm" (ngSubmit)="check($event)" class="form-group">
    <input type="number" formControlName="answer" class="form-control">
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!guessForm.valid" data-toggle="modal" [attr.data-target]="myModal" class="btn btn-success">Check</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It seems you are mixing bootstrap JavaScript and Angular2+. My suggestion would be to use ng-bootstrap : https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

Answer (score 0):

This happens because a `submit` button refreshes the page by default. Try to prevent it whith the following line of code. 
 `$event.preventDefault();` 
Add this as first line in your check method. It should work then.

Comment: Something weird happens: Once the page is loaded, I have to click the button twice in order to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to make a event than control submit button and fire modal as like below. I call it with jquery but you use your desired framework.

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick = "foo();"/>
<script>
    function foo(){
      $('#yourModalId').modal('show'); 
    }
</script>
```

For angular JS you may follow this link :
http://plnkr.co/edit/wfv8P2T1ENg6XkjruzEq?p=preview

Comment: 'modal' in $('#yourModalId').modal('show');  is not recognized as a property of the HTMLElement.

Comment: this is jquery code .. so when you use it you must attach jquery link or CDN: <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>